# rendering artefacts on small objects

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am currently rendering a texture on a cylinder in threeJS.

In most cases it works fine, but I've noticed that when the radius of the cylinder shrinks to low values (in the case of the image attached: `0.0012561892224928503`) I am getting weird artefacts

Is this something that is common in ThreeJS and has some known workarounds for?
I've tried setting logarithmic depthbuffer but that didn't work.

I assume it to be a rounding error somehwere that causes the artifacts, but to my knowledge the default for the renderer precision is `highp` so not much to change there

[image: artefacts]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue I had was with the material and not the renderer.

Or at the very least: I changed my standard material to have `depthTest: false`, which seems to have solved my issue (not sure what other side effects might show up in the future)